# How to pass common data to every page in project

Tags: thymeleaf

**spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1**

**spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf**

I have a bunch of constants that I want to be accessible everywhere.

For example I have organized some constants:

```
public class Constants {
    public final static String LANG = "lang";
}
```

Here I have a param which I already use in two places: in LocaleResolver and in LocaleChangeInterceptor.

And I need on every page where I include this fragment:

```
<th:block th:fragment="top" !doctype html>
    <div>
        <a href="?lang=fr">French</a>
        <a href="?lang=en">Английский</a>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

As we can see, this hardcoded twice. I'd like to avoid such cases.

Is it possible somehow? If a class with static methods is not a good practice, I can use whatever you suggest. Even if such class is preferrable for me, any elegant solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access static variable in Thymeleaf expressions.

```
<th:block th:fragment="top" !doctype html>
    <div>
        <a th:href="|?${T(Constants).LANG}=fr|">French</a>
        <a th:href="|?${T(Constants).LANG}=en|">Английский</a>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

(Where Constants is the full path to your class)

Comment: The question was how to make such a constant visible in every view. That is how to transfer it to every view. Not how to handle it in a view.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between those two... visible in every view vs transferred to every view?

Comment: It is the same. So, how to transfer something to every view.

Comment: The expression `${T(Constants).LANG}` is available in every view in your application (doesn't have to be added on a controller or anything).  Does the other answer work? What are you looking for that is different from `${T(Constants).LANG}`? Are you looking for some kind of session variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a model attribute on a `@ControllerAdvice` so it becomes available automatically in all templates:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute("test")
  public String getTest() {
    return "some-value";
  }
}
```

You can use `test` now in any template:

```
<div th:text="${test}"></div>
```